# Database management on SQL?

Tags: database, database-administration

On SSRS I have a few databases, each with 50+ tables and some of the tables contain 10+ or 100+ columns/attributes.
How to access attributes in each table so I can easily check which table has what attributes, like "reverse engineer" on MySQL?